# Startup Command

Tags: 14.04, scripts, startup

i would like to run this command after my network has been established when i boot up my ubuntu.

the command in the terminal is : "mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyACM0 --baudrate=57600 --out=myipaddress --console"

Where do i need to create this script and how to make it execute after the internet has been detected?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it ok if the command is run *after* log in (and after connection is established)?

Comment: Stratos, did you notice the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your script in `/etc/rc.local`.

This command will be executed at the end on the start of you pc.

Simple you can edit

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

and at the end of file put you command

```
mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyACM0 --baudrate=57600 --out=myipaddress --console &&
```

Comment: but is this going to be executed after the internet has been detected?

Comment: If you have configured cable or wlan connection answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Make the script with executable permissions and copy to the location **/etc/network/if-up.d/** as soon as network ethX up scripts in this location will be triggered.